# Spring Data JPA and cast to a Postgres custom domain

Tags: postgresql, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have the query below:

```
@Query(value="select t.* from titulos t " +
            "where (CAST(:modelosNota AS modelo_nota_fiscal) IS NULL OR t.modelo in (:modelosNota)) order by t.vencimento", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Titulo> relatorioTitulosPagarReceber(@Param("modelosNota") String[] modelosNota);
```

But when it is executed I get the exception below:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: modelo_nota_fiscal = bytea
Dica: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think the message is not very accurate because I already have the type cast to `modelo_nota_fiscal` which is as custom domain type with a check constraint for some values.

When I run the query in PGAdmin it executes normally:

```
select t.* from titulos t where (CAST(null AS modelo_nota_fiscal) IS NULL OR t.modelo in (null)) order by t.vencimento;
```

Or this one that works just fine:

```
select t.* from titulos t where (CAST('NFe' AS modelo_nota_fiscal) IS NULL OR t.modelo in ('NFe')) order by t.vencimento;
```

My entity class as requested:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "titulos")
public class Titulo extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String numero;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short natureza;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short origem;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal valor;

    @Transient
    @Column(name = "valorbaixado")
    private BigDecimal valorBaixado;

    @Transient
    @Column(name = "saldoliquidotitulo")
    private BigDecimal saldoLiquidoTitulo;

    @Transient
    @Column(name = "saldobrutotitulo")
    private BigDecimal saldoBrutoTitulo;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal acrescimo;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal desconto;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal juros;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 4)
    private BigDecimal multa;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate emissao;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate vencimento;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "datamulta")
    private LocalDate dataMulta;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short situacao;

    @Column(length = 2147483647)
    private String observacao;

    @Column(length = 2147483647)
    private String historico;

    @Column(length = 20, name = "documentovinculado")
    private String documentoVinculado;

    @Column(name = "parcela")
    private Integer parcela;

    @Column(name = "totalparcelas")
    private Integer totalParcelas;

    @Column(name = "modelo")
    private String modelo;

    @Column(name = "numerodocumentofiscal")
    private String numeroDocumentoFiscal;

    @Column(name = "seriedocumentofiscal")
    private String serieDocumentoFiscal;

    @Column(name = "subseriedocumentofiscal")
    private String subserieDocumentoFiscal;

    @Column(name = "cfop_codigo")
    private String cfopCodigo;

    @Column(name = "pis_retido", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal pisRetido;

    @Column(name = "cofins_retido ", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal cofinsRetido;

    @Column(name = "csll_retido ", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal csllRetido;

    @Column(name = "irrf_retido  ", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal irrfRetido;

    @Column(name = "inss_retido ", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal inssRetido;

    @Column(name = "iss_retido ", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal issRetido;

    @Column(name = "valor_base ", precision = 20, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal valorBase;

    @Column(name = "competencia")
    private LocalDate competencia;

    @Column(name = "linhadigitavelboleto", length = 44)
    private String linhaDigitavelBoleto;

}
```

Here's my Postgre custom domain type:

```
CREATE DOMAIN public.modelo_nota_fiscal
  AS character varying(3)
  COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
  CONSTRAINT check_modelo_nota_fiscal CHECK (VALUE::text = 'NFs'::text OR VALUE::text = 'NFe'::text OR VALUE::text = 'CEE'::text OR VALUE::text = 'CFG'::text OR VALUE::text = 'CFA'::text);
ALTER DOMAIN public.modelo_nota_fiscal
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON DOMAIN public.modelo_nota_fiscal
  IS 'MODELO NOTA FISCAL: (NFs) Nota Fiscal de Serviço, (NFe) Nota Fiscal Eletrônica, (CEE) Conta de Energia Elétrica, (CFG) Conta de Fornecimento de Gás, (CFA) Conta de Fornecimento de Água.';
```

Does anyone know how am I supposed to cast to a custom Postgres domain using Spring Data JPA?

Comment: Can you put your entity class(es) here? The query itself is not enough

Comment: @C.P.O, the problem is not in my entity class. If I change the query to `select t.* from titulos t where t.modelo in (:modelosNota) order by t.vencimento` and provide hard-coded values to my named-parameter it works just fine.

Comment: @C.P.O, entity class provided.

Comment: I feel it is because of array type you are passing..Can you try to convert it to list and check ..i remember once i faced the same issue because of array type in param..

Comment: @aravind I tried your suggestion but unfortunatelly I had the very same outcome.